# How to exclude some files and extensions from indexing?

Tags: php, indexing

I have this code for indexing directories and files on my site, but I need to exclude some files (`hidden_file.txt` or `hidden_folder`)  and some extensions (`.php` for example). How can I do that?

This is the code, it has a **hide** variable, but I really don't know how to change it for my purpose:

```
 <?php
// Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
{$hide="";}
else
{$hide=".";}

 // Opens directory
 $myDirectory=opendir(".");

// Gets each entry
while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
   $dirArray[]=$entryName;
}

// Closes directory
closedir($myDirectory);

// Counts elements in array
$indexCount=count($dirArray);

// Sorts files
sort($dirArray);

// Loops through the array of files
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

// Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
    if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1)!=$hide) {
// Gets File Names
    $name=$dirArray[$index];
    $namehref=$dirArray[$index];
$path =$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$nome= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

// Output
 echo("
 <li><a class='color' href='$nome$path$namehref'>$name</a></li>");
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$hide` variable only purpose is to hide every file name starting by a dot : "." and ".." and ".whatever" (current folder, parent folder, and hidden files) from results.

```
// Gets each entry
while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
   $ext = pathinfo($myDirectory . PATH_SEPARATOR . $entryName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if(in_array($ext, array('php', 'secret', 'hidden'))){continue;} //Here the extension list you don't want to show
   if(strpos(strtolower($entryName, 'hidden'))){continue;} //add as much rules as you want like so (this one means, if there is "hidden" in the filename, pass to the next file.
   if(strpos(strtolower($entryName, 'secret'))){continue;}
   $dirArray[]=$entryName; //if the filename has passed all rules it gets added to the list.
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i tried the code, but it gives me the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING) at line if($ext in array('php', 'secret', 'hidden')){continue;} also if i remove that line, it shows me a blank page, it doesn't index any file, i am missing something?

Comment: it's in_array, my bad, too much python lately :') I've edited my answer.

Comment: nope, it gives the same error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in_array'"

Comment: it shows a blank page now, but no problem, i'll move the files i need to hide in other directory, thanks for your answer, even if it doesn't work, i learned something new on php

Comment: obviously after the while loop you have to echo the data.
For instance using : `var_dump($dirArray);` ...